# PLS-000428 error Oracle stored procedure with CTE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am stuck in an issue while trying to create an Oracle stored procedure. I am providing the skeleton of the code below.

```
Create or replace procedure "SP_UPDATE_DATA" AS
BEGIN
WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT A.F1, A.F2 ,B.F3 FROM A, B WHERE A.X1=B.X1
),
CTE2 AS
(
SELECT A.F1,A.F2,C.F5
FROM
CTE1 A,C
WHERE A.F1=C.F1
)
UPDATE TABLE MAIN
SET XYZ=CTE2.F2
FROM
CTE2
WHERE
MAIN.F1.CTE2.F2
```

When I am trying to compile the procedure I am getting error

> AN INTO CLAUSE IS EXPECTED IN SELECT

Though I am actually not using any variable, also not returning anything not selecting anything, still facing the error. Not sure if it has to do something with the CTE.

Need your input to reach a resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Update .. from` is not correct syntax in oracle.

Comment: You may need `merge` instead of `update`

Comment: Thanks , you can assume UPDATE ..FROM syntax is correct, But still the above mentioned error is showing.

Comment: Because, need to return the results of a select statement into a variable, or a cursor within a PL/SQL code.

Comment: "You can assume UPDATE ..FROM syntax is correct".  Yes we can do that, the problem is (as with many assumptions) it is a *completely False assumption*. Oracle does not support the "Update...From"  syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It should looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_update_data
AS
BEGIN
   
   UPDATE MAIN
      SET XYZ = ( WITH
                     CTE1 AS
                     ( SELECT A.F1, A.F2, B.F3
                         FROM A, B
                        WHERE A.X1=B.X1
                     ),
                     CTE2 AS
                     ( SELECT A.F1, A.F2, C.F5
                         FROM CTE1 A, C
                        WHERE A.F1=C.F1
                     )
                  SELECT CTE2.F2
                    FROM CTE2
                   WHERE MAIN.F1=CTE2.F2
                );

END sp_update_data;
/
```